# Cutting a fixed number of characters at each CTRL+X, or some key combination?

Tags: kate

You know how, when you need to indent all the lines of a block of code the same amount, you can copy that many blank spaces and CTRL+V and arrow down/home and make pretty quick progress?

It it possible to perform the reverse? That is, when one needs to, for example, split a function into separate functions and the code that was indented within some conditional
statements needs to be shifted left, is there a way to set an equivalent of CTRL+X to delete a fixed number of characters each time instead of pressing delete repeatedly on every line? Sort of like the opposite of copy/paste, just cut a fixed number of characters at each CTRL+X.

I'm not using any auto-indentation settings, just using the spacebar.

Can a keyboard action be configured to delete a fixed number of characters in front of the cursor regardless of their content and without having to select them first? For example, make CTRL+X delete ten characters to the right of the cursor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) does this pretty easily already.

**Add a tab to multiple lines by selecting multiple lines and pressing tab:**
[image]

**Deleting a tab from multiple lines by selecting multiple lines and pressing shift-tab:**
[image]

**Deleting space from multiple lines by hold control-alt and selecting the space you want to delete (you can also insert data to multiple lines simultaneously this way):**
[image]